# How do you work out the base of an isosceles triangle with all other sides and angles given?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I have the sides of the triangle as $2613$ m and $2613$ m for each one. The top angle is $174$ degrees and the bottom angles are $3$ degrees each. How do I work this out? (please give method not just answer)

Comment: I am not sure whether this is geometrically possible to solve. If you use trigonometry, you will find that base$=2(2613*\cos 3)$

Comment: Use the cosine rule.

Comment: The sine law will also directly give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In isosceles triangle altitude to the base is also median of the base and bisector of the vertex angle. So draw the altitude and you will get right triangle with hypotenuse $2613$ and angle opposite half of the base equal to $87°$. Thus half of the base is $2613 \cdot \sin 87° \approx 2609.4$.